# sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error opening OutputStream: Invalid number of channels

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, python-sounddevice

My code is:

```
import scipy.io as sio
import sounddevice as sd
xx= sio.loadmat('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\Rabia Ahmad spring 2016\\FYP\\1. Matlab Work\\record work\\aa.mat')['aa']
sd.play(xx,64000)
```

I got the error **sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error opening OutputStream: Invalid number of channels**

Comment: What is `xx.shape`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser its (1,4999)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a comment, you said that `xx` has shape `(1, 4999)`.  `sounddevice.play` is interpreting this as a *single* sample with 4999 channels!

Try [transposing the array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html), so `play` sees the array as 4999 samples of a signal with 1 channel:

```
sd.play(xx.T, 64000)
```